# matTable with toggle-able sticky columns

Tags: html, css, angular, mat-table

I prepared a table with toggle-able sticky columns. User can click on the header and make it a sticky column.
I tried and the columns are toggling but when i scroll the selected columns are no more sticky.
Below is the url of replicating the problem. is there anything am missing. Thanks in advance.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yka4tq?file=src/app/table-sticky-complex-flex-example.html

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find the solution for the above qu

```js
 this.selectedColumnsList = ['header1'];
 
 isSticky(id: string) {
    return (this.selectedColumnsList || []).indexOf(id) !== -1;
  }

  public headerPinning = (headerName): void => {
    
    let idx = this.selectedColumnsList.findIndex(item => item === headerName);
    if (idx < 0) {
      this.selectedColumnsList.push(headerName);
    } else {
      this.selectedColumnsList.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  }
```

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="originRamp" [sticky]="isSticky('header1')">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Origin Ramp
                                <mat-icon svgIcon="pin" class="pin-icon"
                                    (click)="headerPinning('header1')">
                                </mat-icon>
                            </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.header1}} </td>
                            <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>  header1 Footer </td>
                        </ng-container>
```